# numpy conditioning values by the index within a axis

Tags: python, numpy

```
ar = np.arange(2*3*3).reshape(2, 3, 3)
```

I want to initialize a boolean numpy array filled with `True`, but only give `False` for elements of the second position of the axis 2. The desired array is

```
array([[[ True, False,  True],
        [ True, False,  True],
        [ True, False,  True]],

       [[ True, False,  True],
        [ True, False,  True],
        [ True, False,  True]]])
```

Comment: do you need to calculate the array or can you use your example?

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in the example code. Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.ones_like`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones_like.html) and [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with a boolean AND (`&`):

```
ar = np.arange(2*3*3).reshape(2, 3, 3)

out = np.ones_like(ar, dtype=bool) & [[[True, False, True]]]
```

Output:

```
array([[[ True, False,  True],
        [ True, False,  True],
        [ True, False,  True]],

       [[ True, False,  True],
        [ True, False,  True],
        [ True, False,  True]]])
```

Alternatively, using indexing and selecting the midpoint of the last dimension (assuming an odd number):

```
out = np.ones_like(ar, dtype=bool)

out[..., out.shape[-1]//2] = False
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though the way is not I am looking for, the second probably works as well.

Comment: *How* is it not what you're looking for, and what exactly are you looking for? ;)

Comment: Why `out.shape[-1]//2`? OP's question indicates they just want `out[..., 1] = False`

Comment: @pho well this was a demonstration of a possible generalization (here to the middle element) in case the shape is dynamic, of course the position `1` can be hardcoded.

Comment: I wanted to know how to directly ask to an array this question: "which axis are you at and which position at the axis are you in?" I will get the array(s) in the same shape with info of the indices of axis and position at the axis for all elements. Then, one can use this info to solve my question via a normal indexing and slicing... like `ar.where(ar_axis_info==2 and ar_position_info==1, False, True)`